# Import xml with Feeds module. Only one value is imported

Tags: importing-exporting, feeds

I have a xml (http://pastebin.com/q64L3ECX) that I need to import with Feeds module into my site. Basically, with this xml example, I need to import 3 nodes where my GUID (set as unique) is "test_case". Each test_case is inside a test_set.

The problem is that I can only get the first test_case of each of the two test_set of that file. Can someone help me understand what is wrong?

[image: Drupal Xpath Parser Settings]

Debug output:

```
xpathparser:0 :
<test_set_name tl_label="Name" tl_name="name" tl_physicalname="CY_CYCLE">GUI.00 Launch Applications</test_set_name>
<test_set_name tl_label="Name" tl_name="name" tl_physicalname="CY_CYCLE">GUI.02 EM NE.000 EM NE Generic.Generic EM NE tests</test_set_name>
xpathparser:1 :
<test_case_name tp_label="Test Name" tp_name="name" tp_physicalname="TS_NAME">Launch TNMS</test_case_name>
<test_case_name tp_label="Test Name" tp_name="name" tp_physicalname="TS_NAME">Open</test_case_name>
<test_case_name tp_label="Test Name" tp_name="name" tp_physicalname="TS_NAME">ManualNetworkScan</test_case_name>

Created 1 node.
```

Comment: You can try to use "/report/test_sets/*"

Comment: Thanks ar7max but that doesn't solve the problem. Maybe I can't get both the test_case and the test_set?

Comment: I added the output of my import. The 2 test_sets and 3 test_cases are there so why only 1 node is created? If I use ar7max suggestion I get no nodes.

Comment: I tried changing the context to "//report/test_sets/test_set|//report/test_sets/test_set/test_cases/test_case" and now 5 nodes are created. The problem is that I need 3 nodes, 2 with one test_set and the other with the corresponding test_set.

Comment: The problem as I can see in relation test_set 1:n test_case

Comment: Yes, there is a test_set 1:n test_case relation. So, as Feeds is implemented I can't import as I want right? I don't know how can I import this data and still keep the relationship between the elements.

Comment: Now Im able to import your xml but I need more info about your content type/entities structure to understand what concrete do you want.

Comment: Hi ar7max, really appreciate your help. Here is my content type (simplified): http://tinyurl.com/o4bw3dq. So, each node created should have both test_set_name and test_case_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, our *relation's key* will be test case's GUID (Test cases (Entity reference by Feeds GUID) (field_test_cases)):

- Content type `test_set`:

  - `field_test_cases`: Type - Entity Reference, Target type - Test case
    (type test_case), Number of values - unlimited.
- Content type `test_case`: standard Title and Body fields.

Test case's importer's config:

```
$feeds_importer = new stdClass();
$feeds_importer->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default feeds_importer disabled initially */
$feeds_importer->api_version = 1;
$feeds_importer->id = 'test_cases';
$feeds_importer->config = array(
  'name' => 'Test cases',
  'description' => '',
  'fetcher' => array(
    'plugin_key' => 'FeedsFileFetcher',
    'config' => array(
      'allowed_extensions' => 'txt csv tsv xml opml html htm',
      'direct' => FALSE,
      'directory' => 'public://feeds',
      'allowed_schemes' => array(
        0 => 'public',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'parser' => array(
    'plugin_key' => 'FeedsXPathParserXML',
    'config' => array(
      'sources' => array(
        'xpathparser:0' => 'text()',
        'xpathparser:1' => 'text()',
      ),
      'rawXML' => array(
        'xpathparser:0' => 0,
        'xpathparser:1' => 0,
      ),
      'context' => '/report/test_sets/test_set/test_cases/test_case/test_case_name',
      'exp' => array(
        'errors' => 0,
        'debug' => array(
          'context' => 0,
          'xpathparser:0' => 0,
          'xpathparser:1' => 0,
        ),
      ),
      'allow_override' => 1,
    ),
  ),
  'processor' => array(
    'plugin_key' => 'FeedsNodeProcessor',
    'config' => array(
      'expire' => '-1',
      'author' => 0,
      'authorize' => 1,
      'mappings' => array(
        0 => array(
          'source' => 'xpathparser:0',
          'target' => 'guid',
          'unique' => 1,
        ),
        1 => array(
          'source' => 'xpathparser:1',
          'target' => 'title',
          'unique' => 1,
        ),
      ),
      'update_existing' => '1',
      'update_non_existent' => 'skip',
      'input_format' => 'plain_text',
      'skip_hash_check' => 1,
      'bundle' => 'test_case',
    ),
  ),
  'content_type' => '',
  'update' => 0,
  'import_period' => '-1',
  'expire_period' => 3600,
  'import_on_create' => 1,
  'process_in_background' => 0,
);
```

Test set's importer's config:

```
$feeds_importer = new stdClass();
$feeds_importer->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default feeds_importer disabled initially */
$feeds_importer->api_version = 1;
$feeds_importer->id = 'test_set';
$feeds_importer->config = array(
  'name' => 'Test set',
  'description' => '',
  'fetcher' => array(
    'plugin_key' => 'FeedsFileFetcher',
    'config' => array(
      'allowed_extensions' => 'txt csv tsv xml opml html htm',
      'direct' => FALSE,
      'directory' => 'public://feeds',
      'allowed_schemes' => array(
        0 => 'public',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'parser' => array(
    'plugin_key' => 'FeedsXPathParserXML',
    'config' => array(
      'sources' => array(
        'xpathparser:0' => 'test_set_name/text()',
        'xpathparser:1' => 'test_set_name/text()',
        'xpathparser:2' => 'test_cases/test_case/test_case_name/text()',
      ),
      'rawXML' => array(
        'xpathparser:0' => 0,
        'xpathparser:1' => 0,
        'xpathparser:2' => 0,
      ),
      'context' => '/report/test_sets/test_set',
      'exp' => array(
        'errors' => 0,
        'debug' => array(
          'context' => 0,
          'xpathparser:0' => 0,
          'xpathparser:1' => 0,
          'xpathparser:2' => 0,
        ),
      ),
      'allow_override' => 1,
    ),
  ),
  'processor' => array(
    'plugin_key' => 'FeedsNodeProcessor',
    'config' => array(
      'expire' => '-1',
      'author' => 0,
      'authorize' => 1,
      'mappings' => array(
        0 => array(
          'source' => 'xpathparser:0',
          'target' => 'guid',
          'unique' => 1,
        ),
        1 => array(
          'source' => 'xpathparser:1',
          'target' => 'title',
          'unique' => 1,
        ),
        2 => array(
          'source' => 'xpathparser:2',
          'target' => 'field_test_cases',
          'unique' => FALSE,
        ),
      ),
      'update_existing' => '1',
      'update_non_existent' => 'skip',
      'input_format' => 'plain_text',
      'skip_hash_check' => 1,
      'bundle' => 'test_set',
    ),
  ),
  'content_type' => '',
  'update' => 0,
  'import_period' => '-1',
  'expire_period' => 3600,
  'import_on_create' => 1,
  'process_in_background' => 0,
);
```

Comment: Hi ar7max, that returns 0 nodes. The debug I get: http://pastebin.com/wDmdA7bT; My content type: http://picpaste.com/pics/Untitled-4DKRUBkw.1440366806.png (field_test_set_name allows 1 value; field_test_case_name allows unlimited as you said); My mappings in feeds: http://picpaste.com/pics/Untitled-Hn1LPyFD.1440366909.png

Comment: Very interesting, cuz was parsed right. Mb something with node processor's settings in part of updating existing nodes and mb you should try to check skip hash check

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It worked. 2 Nodes created, 1 with one test_case. 2 with two test_cases. For this example its good but If I add more fields (test cases fields), I loose the relationship again. I really think that the best way is to do it with a custom module and have the control myself.

Comment: If u can provide more info about structure and your needs I will be able to try.

Comment: Can we make a chat? If you can, it would be easier.

Comment: You can contact me via skype under same nickname